# PyQt and py2exe or cx_freeze: AttributeError

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe, cx-freeze

Here I have Python 2.7.3 (x64), PyQt 4.9.5-1 (x64) running on Win7 x64. I want to convert a simple PyQt script to an exe file.
This is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt

a = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

def sayHello():
    print "Hello, World!"

hellobutton = Qt.QPushButton("Say 'Hello world!'",None)

a.connect(hellobutton, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), sayHello)

hellobutton.show()
a.exec_()
```

Running it from the command line works as expected.
I use a setup.py for py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['pyqt-example.py'])
```

However, if I try to convert it to an exe file with py2exe 0.6.9 with `python setup.py py2exe`, I get this error when running the exe file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqt-example.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QApplication'
```

I also tried cx_freeze 4.3 with `\Python27\Scripts\cxfreeze pyqt-example.py --target-dir dist`. This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "pyqt-example.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QApplication'
```

So I assume that I missed to inform both of these tools about the location of some Qt components. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `QtGui.QApplication` instead of `Qt.QApplication`?

Comment: If I do this, the script itself won't run anymore: `NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined`

Comment: You did change the import from `from PyQt4 import Qt` to `from PyQt4 import QtGui`?.
Also take into account that importing `PyQt4.Qt` loads _all_ modules, while importing `PyQt4.QtGui` loads only what you need.

Comment: The script works fine as stated above - there are only problems if I treat it with py2exe or cx_freeze. However, if I do your changes and use cx_freeze with it, the error message changes to: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QPushButton'`

Comment: Packing PyQt applications with py2exe or cx_freeze requires extra workarounds and `Qt` module in `PyQt4` is just a convenience module for importing everything. It's possible those workarounds used by these package systems does not include `Qt`. Try to use explicit names for `QtGui`, `QtCore` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Avaris, your hint was correct. Avoiding the use of module Qt is the answer. This is the script which works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

def sayHello():
    print "Hello, World!"

hellobutton = QtGui.QPushButton("Say 'Hello world!'",None)

a.connect(hellobutton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), sayHello)

hellobutton.show()
a.exec_()
```

After that, I have to call cx_freeze so: `cxfreeze pyqt-example.py --include-modules atexit --target-dir dist`. And it works!